# Including a Chef LWRP from another cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I wrote a small LWRP my `app` cookbook (`trim_log`), and it works. However, now I am trying to move this particular LWRP in to the `commons` cookbook so that my other cookbooks can also use it. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to load in the `trim_log` resource/provider in to any of the cookbooks, including my `app` cookbook.

```
├── app
│   ├── recipes
│       └── default.rb
├── commons
   ├── providers
   │   └── trim_log.rb
   └── resources
       └── trim_log.rb
```

I have defined the `trim_log` provider/resource in the commons cookbook. Now I wish to use this `trim_log` provider/resource in the `app` cookbook. How can I make it available there?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you need to:

- Declare in the `app/metadata.rb` that you depend on the `commons` cookbook.
- Refer to the resource as `commons_trim_log` in `app/recipes/default.rb`.

Comment: I didn't realize you had to specify the dependency of `commons` in the `app` cookbook's `metadata.rb`. That fixed it, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are working with multiple cookbooks, you should check out [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com) and [Foodcritic](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/), both of which will push you to write better `metadata.rb` files.